# No instance for show, in Lambda function?

Tags: haskell, lambda

This works fine in ghci:

```
printRobot (fight killerRobot gentleGiant)
```

**But this throws me a "No instance for show" error, and I can't seem to see why.**

```
threeRoundFight a b = 
(\a b -> printRobot (fight a b))
```

This is the error:

```
• No instance for (Show
                     ((((t40, t50, t50) -> t50) -> t60)
                      -> (((t20, t10, t60) -> ((t20, t10, t60) -> t0) -> t0)
                          -> (([Char], a10, a0) -> [Char]) -> t30)
                      -> t30))
    arising from a use of ‘print’
    (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
• In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘it’
  In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

Here is the necessary functions to consider:

```
fight aRobot defender = damage defender attack
where attack = if getHP aRobot > 10
            then getAttack aRobot
            else 0

printRobot aRobot = aRobot(\(n,a,h)->n ++ " attack:" ++ (show a) ++ " hp: " ++ (show h))

robot (name,attack,hp) = \message -> message (name,attack,hp)
```

Here are the Robots(what I put in as parameters, namely killerRobot and gentleGiant):

```
killerRobot = robot ("killer",25,200)
gentleGiant = robot ("Mr.Friendly", 10, 300)
```

Also as you can see I'm trying to make this a **threeRound**Fight, with the help of overwriting the robots with nested lambdas. But I can't seem to understand how to continue on from the first fight if I get it working.

Comment: Why do you here use `aRboto (..)`? in `printRobot?

Comment: So I can choose which robot to print? aRobot is just a variable?

Comment: Well you make it rather hard to understand by not using a `data`type, but representing a fobot essentially as a function that maps a function that maps 3-tuple to something, to that something. Although that is essentially how one "stores" data in lambda calculus, it here makes things a lot more complicated.

Comment: ah, yeah I can understand that.. this is my second attempt to learn and understand haskell and the book hasn't come to datatypes yet so I just stay out of it until it says otherwise.

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: "Get programming with haskell", but I have to say that Datatypes started right after this chapter.

Answer (score 6):

The line

```
threeRoundFight a b = (\a b -> printRobot (fight a b))
```

is equivalent to

```
threeRoundFight x y = (\a b -> printRobot (fight a b))
             -- ^^^ unused variables
```

(If you enable warnings, GHC helps you in detecting this error)

This is not what you want. You likely want

```
threeRoundFight = (\a b -> printRobot (fight a b))
-- or
threeRoundFight a b = printRobot (fight a b)
```

Comment: Oh, that makes total sense but the first line you gave me I have already tried before. It doesn't work. I get this "Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘printRobot’" when I do that. And the second line I can't do because I'm working with lambdas and trying to understand what the book means by overwriting variables with nested lambdas :/. Either way your explanation helped me understand a little bit better.

Comment: @ruubel Ambiguous type variables arise when your code does not clearly specify which types to use. I'd recommend to annotate your source code, adding an explicit type signature to all the top-level functions (or at least enough of them). Often, that fixes many issues.

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree. I think it's weird that the book hasn't covered that yet. It just told me to do these exercises without them. Thank you for your help.